# Running 'show process list' simultaneously

Tags: mysql, rhel6

I have two scripts put into a cron that runs every single minute. Both the scripts connect to the same database and runs a `show full processlist`. Is it okay if two `show full processlist` commands are run at the same time?

P.S:- One of the scripts will be removed in a week or so, so this setup is only for one week at the most.

Comment: hmmm....just for curiosity what specific problem are you worried about?

Comment: I am writing a monitoring script to replace the current monitoring script which is very 'messy'. It is being written in Python and gets the output of `show full processlist` to create the data. So, for a week or so we will be running these two scripts together. Just wanted to make sure it is okay to run multiple `show full processlist` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is OK. Even if not, it would be MySQL's job to deal with the problem, e.g. by delaying the second until the first is finished.

Answer (score 1):

What is the difference between `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` and `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` ?

- `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` displays the first 100 characters of the INFO column
- `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` displays the entire INFO column

From the [**INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/processlist-table.html) point-of-view:

- `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` effectively runs `SELECT ID,USER,HOST,DB,COMMAND,TIME,STATE,LEFT(INFO,100) INFO FROM information_schema.processlist;`
- `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` effectively runs `SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist;`

There is only one circumstance I can think of  where **you do not want to run** `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`.

When you a loading a mysqldump into a MySQL instance, you run `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` to track the progress of a table's load. We know that mysqldumps have extended INSERTs. That single INSERT can have hundreds, or even thousands, or rows. If you run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`, you can spill the text representation of those hundreds, or even thousands, or rows to the console or to a log. That can quickly generate huge logs of SQL queries with data visible as plain text.

So, be very careful not to be running multiple `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` commands during a load of a mysqldump.

If you have do some monitoring of the processlist, you can either

- Run `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`
- Run `SELECT ID,USER,HOST,DB,COMMAND,TIME,STATE,LEFT(INFO,300) INFO FROM information_schema.processlist;` (setting LEFT(INFO,xxx) to whatever manageable length)